# Python dictionary with tuples as key to new dictionary with keys as first element of tuple

Tags: list, dictionary, tuples

I would like to convert the dictionary d1 to dictionary d2:

```
d1 = {('a','b'):1, ('a','c'):2, ('a','d'):3, ('b','c'):2, ('b','d'):1, ('c','f'):2, ('f','c'):2 }

d2 = {'a': [('b',1),('c',2) ,('d',3)], 'b':[('c',2),('d',1)], 'c':[('f',2)], 'f':[('c',2)]}
```

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use for loop and loop through the dictionary, then make a new dictionary with your tuple first element as key

```
base = {('a','b'):1, ('a','c'):2, ('a','d'):3, ('b','c'):2, ('b','d'):1, ('c','f'):2, ('f','c'):2 }
newDict = {}
for key in base:
    #Key is the tuple
    if not key[0] in newDict.keys():
        newDict[key[0]] = []
    newDict[key[0]].insert(0, (key[1], base[key]))

print(newDict)
```

If you don't really care about the order of the list in new dictionary value, you should append instead of insert on 0 index, because insert on 0 index is slower than append.

Comment: This is so cool. Thank you very much Ahmad.